# How to get Facebook public profile data using angularfire auth, firebase in an Ionic 2 App

Tags: facebook, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I'm trying to get data from users' Facebook pages who login/signup in my app with Facebook like birthday, images, gender etc. Right now I'm just adding arbitrary values to my database but I want to get their gender, profile picture url, and birthday if possible. For the life of me I can't figure out how to do it. Here's what I have so far:

```
loginWithFacebook() {
return Observable.create(observer => {
  if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
    Facebook.login(['public_profile', 'email']).then(facebookData => {
      console.log(facebookData);
      let provider = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(facebookData.authResponse.accessToken);
      firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(provider).then(firebaseData => {
        this.af.database.list('users').update(firebaseData.uid, {
          name: firebaseData.displayName,
          email: firebaseData.email,
          provider: 'facebook',
          keys: firebaseData.keys,
          birthday: firebaseData.birthday,
          snapchat: firebaseData.snapchat,
          gender: firebaseData.gender,
          image: firebaseData.photoURL
        });

        observer.next();
      });
    }, error => {
      observer.error(error);
    });
  } else {
    this.af.auth.login({
      provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
      method: AuthMethods.Popup,
    }).then((facebookData) => {
      console.log(facebookData);
      this.af.database.list('users').update(facebookData.auth.uid, {
        name: facebookData.auth.displayName,
        email: facebookData.auth.email,
        provider: 'facebook',
        keys: 5,
        birthday: 'w',
        snapchat: 'w',
        gender: 'male',
        image: facebookData.auth.photoURL
      });
      observer.next();
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.info("error", error);
      observer.error(error);
    });
  }
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by Firebase. You have to make the extra api call to Facebook to get that data using the Facebook Access Token (make sure the desired scopes were prompted when getting that access token).

`AJAX GET 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' + credential.accessToken`